# (x:y) operator in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I am trying to understand this code:

```
  r = (1:10) - (4/1)
    println(r)
```

> Output:
>
> -3.0:1.0:6.0

I understood why I got `-3` and `6`. But why I got that value in the middle **(1.0)**? How does Julia calculate it? Or how I can google it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(first:step:last)` syntax represent a `Range` type in Julia

```
typeof(1:10) # => UnitRange{Int32}
```

If step part is omitted, by default it is assumed `1`

```
1:10 == 1:1:10 # => true
```

A `Range` is a compact view of a series

```
collect(1:10) # => 10-element Array{Int32,1}:
#  1
#  2
#  3
#  4
#  5
#  6
#  7
#  8
#  9
# 10
```

So it's expected that a `Range` type and a `Vector` follow the same rules e.g when you add a constant value like this:

```
collect(1+(1:10))==collect(1:10)+1 # => true
```

or even adding two vectors give you the same result of adding their range representation like this:

```
collect((1:10)+(1:10))==collect(1:10)+collect(1:10) # => true
```

Comment: It is probably just a typo, but it is not true that `1:10 === 1:1:10`, only that `1:10 == 1:1:10`. The first is a `UnitRange` and the second is a `StepRange`. It might also good to mention that `isa(1:10,AbstractVector) # => true`.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for his comment on `1:10 !== 1:1:10` really it was a typo, I edit that. now `1:10 == 1:1:10 # => true`

Answer (score 3):

The division operator in `4/1` returns a `Float64`. Although the original Range is a size 1 `Int` step Range, after adding a floating point to both sides it becomes a `Float64` Range. As such, a step size of 1.0 is created by converting the implicit integer step size (floating point numbers are non-uniformly distributed, so uniform stepping is a little tricky - sometimes there are rounding issues).

Answer (score 2):

You can see this when applying `float` to an interval:

```
julia> 1:10
1:10

julia> float(1:10)
1.0:1.0:10.0
```

and this promotion is required before adding to the Float64 `4/1` (`4.0`).

Similarly, when adding an integer to a float julia "promotes" the integer to a float before adding/subtracting:

```
julia> 1 + 2.0
3.0

julia> @which 1 + 2.0
+(x::Number, y::Number) at promotion.jl:172
```

see [the promotion rules](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/004059abfb12b7663a05ae8b1d16674c45e18a96/base/promotion.jl#L172-L176):

```
+(x::Number, y::Number) = +(promote(x,y)...)
```

You can `@which` follow the function calls all the way down to understand what's going on (all the way to [the following](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5d7f2de050a5180b59fa973906631e11fb94aaca/base/range.jl#L602)):

```
julia> @which +(1:10, 2.0)
+(A::AbstractArray{T,N}, x::Number) at arraymath.jl

julia> @which .+(1:10, 2.0)
.+(r::Range{T}, x::Real) at range.jl

julia> @which .+(2.0, 1:10)
.+(x::Real, r::UnitRange{T<:Real}) at range.jl

# which is defined as
.+(x::Real, r::UnitRange)  = range(x + r.start, length(r))
```

and hence promotion-addition of Int64 and Float64.

---

Note in master the display of interval is slightly less confusing/ambiguous:

```
julia> float(1:10)
10-element FloatRange{Float64}:
 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0

julia> 1:10
10-element UnitRange{Int64}:
 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```